# Google Chart (Material) - Type Bar - Data in arrayToDataTable with role style KO?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to use a google bar chart (material design) with the options provided in the arrayToDataTable to customize the color of the bar.

**Example:**

```
return google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['1', '2', {role: 'style'}],
      ['1', 1000, '#000000'],
      ['2', 1170, '#000000'],
      ['3', 660, '#000000'],
      ['4', 1030, '#000000']
    ]);
```

As you can see, if I refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format), the bar should be in black.
It is not.
Moreover, this third column is not added (so something catch it as an role, but do not execute associated behavior).

I saw multiples topics about it nevertheless they were working with old packages (not material design).

Thanks for the help guys.

**Update 1:**

- Replaced `#00000` color to `#000000` (doesn't solve the problem, I just forgot a 0 when writing this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, [column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) **do not work** with *material* charts

along with [several configuration options](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

recommend using *core* chart instead

there is a configuration option that will style a *core* chart as *material*

`theme: 'material'`

but it's not exact, see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart(transparent) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['1', '2', {role: 'style'}],
    ['1', 1000, '#000000'],
    ['2', 1170, '#000000'],
    ['3', 660, '#000000'],
    ['4', 1030, '#000000']
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

also, the style column value for **black** should have six zeroes vs. five

--> `'#000000'`

vs.

--> `'#00000'`

Comment: Yes it helps, that's a shame that a simple option like this do not exist, but whatever, thanks for the tips about 'theme', it helps !