# How to set a specific color for a specific bar in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I set a specific color for a specific bar in Google charts?

I tried to apply this coloring style, but nothing seems to work!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_material" style="width: 'auto'; height: 500px;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Statistics', 'Amount', { role: 'style' }],
        ['Categories', 5, '#D9534F'],
        ['Posts', 4, '#337AB7'],
        ['Comments', 8, '#5CB85C'],
        ['Users', 3, '#F0AD4E'],
      ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Analysis',
        subtitle: '',
      },
    /*  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'], // Another coloring method*/
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

I think that this list contains the coloring feature, and is not to be supported at the moment... Please answer if you think that this is not true!
https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143
As for the "classic" graphs, then the solution provided by @عارف بن الأزرق is definitely working on those graphs. Yet, I'm never interested in them!

Comment: column roles are not supported by _material_ charts, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) for options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out - as Mr. WhiteHat cleared out - that the Material Charts do not support the majority of the useful customization options just yet... Which are all listed here:

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143

Hence, I'm obliged - as Mr. عارف بن الأزرق suggested - to use the Core Charts ALONG WITH the "material" theme provided in the following question's answer:

[Google Chart (Material) - Type Bar - Data in arrayToDataTable with role style KO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473417/google-chart-material-type-bar-data-in-arraytodatatable-with-role-style-ko)

Answer (score 0):

Following the [fiddle provided by googl](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)e
I changed `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});`
and   
 
`var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);`
and it's working
here a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vu5e2tfz/)  of your code

Comment: Hmm... As far as I'm concerned, you have used a different bar-graph style! The code is working accordingly, but without the appearance that I'd rather have. Is there any other method to provide colors to that bar-graph?

Comment: Ok you need matrial chart then you cant add role style in matrial chart the solution is to use corechart with theme matrial, the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473417/google-chart-material-type-bar-data-in-arraytodatatable-with-role-style-ko

Comment: Roger that. Thanks.